# Vue Router Universal Navbar Search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, search, router

new to Vue and frontend dev in general.

I'm trying to make a universal nav bar in Vue Router using bootstrap vue with a search bar implemented.

However, because I have my nav bar placed in App.vue, it is unable to pass the search function to specific routes.

Here is what I have in my App.vue

```
  <div id="app" >
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" variant="light" type="light" class="justify-content-between">
      <b-navbar-brand><router-link to="/">Brand</router-link></b-navbar-brand>
      <b-collapse class="nav-collapse" is-nav>
        <b-nav-item><router-link to="/about">Route 1</router-link></b-nav-item>
      </b-collapse>

      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <b-nav-form>
          <b-form-input class="form-control mr-sm-2" v-model="search_term" placeholder="Search..."></b-form-input>
          <b-button variant="outline-success my-2 my-sm-2" type="submit" v-on:click="getSearch(search_term)">Search</b-button>
        </b-nav-form>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-navbar>

    <router-view/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style>


</style>
```

The router functions are in its own class

As you can see the search stuff I have implemented under b-nav-form is from when the navbar was in a specific page where the functions are implemented.

However, with a navbar in individual pages, it has to be re-rendered every time the user re-routes. So I put it in the App.vue page, where it is permanently rendered.

How can I pass the search_term to its specific function in its specific page while the navbar being universal? Is that possible? Or is it easier to just keep the navbar in its own page.

Comment: Please don't forget to review the answer provided. Mark it as valid or comment to explain why it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to share a navbar accross your app and using its data through any route component is to keep it at the App.vue level as you thought.
The tricky part is then to access the search in the route components, but that pretty easy using a Vuex store.

The Vuex store is a centralised source of truth for your app. Any component, as deeply burried in your app structure as imaginable, can access it through this.$store or other API ([Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/))

All you have to do is store your search value in it and let all your component access it as needed.

Minimal example below:

```js
const mainComponent = Vue.component("mainComponent", {
  computed: {
    search() {
      return this.$store.state.search
    }
  },
  template: "<div><div>Main component</div><div>Search: {{ search }}</div><div><router-link to='/other'>Go to Other</router-link></div></div>"
});
const otherComponent = Vue.component("otherComponent", {
  computed: {
    search() {
      return this.$store.state.search
    }
  },
  template: "<div><div>Other component</div><div>Search: {{ search }}</div><div><router-link to='/'>Go to Main</router-link></div></div>"
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    search: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    search(state, payload) {
      state.search = payload;
    }
  }
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: "*",
      redirect: "/"
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      component: mainComponent
    },
    {
      path: "/other",
      component: otherComponent
    }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  router,
  data: {
    searchValue: ''
  },
  methods: {
    submitSearch() {
      this.$store.commit("search", this.searchValue);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.4.8/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitSearch">
      <input type="text" v-model="searchValue" placeholder="search" />
      <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</div>
```